# What is the proper idiomatic way of checking if a map has no elements in coffeescript?

Tags: dictionary, coffeescript

since a code example is worth a thousand words:

```
console.log(@searchEnginesMap, {}, @searchEnginesMap == {}, @searchEnginesMap is {}, @searchEnginesMap.empty?, @searchEnginesMap.length)
```

returns:

```
{} {} false false false undefined
```

what's the correct syntax to get a true value for this? (or how should I correctly check if I have a map with zero elements?)

EDIT: extra credit:

how do you compare these two dictionaries to have them be the same (by value, not be reference):

```
a = {"foo":"bar?q=%s","baz":"qux?q=%s"}
b = {"foo":"bar?q=%s","baz":"qux?q=%s"}
```

so I need to know what I can use to get get true while comparing these?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no CoffeeScript magic solution here. If you want to know if an Object is empty then you have to count the keys. You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
if Object.keys(obj).length == 0
  # obj is empty
```

Or you could use a loop:

```
if (true for v of obj).length == 0
  # obj is empty
```

The `for ... of` loop version could be wrapped in a short-circuiting function without much effort.

I would probably wimp out and grab Underscore or Lodash so that I could use [`_.isEmpty`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEmpty):

```
if _(obj).isEmpty()
  # obj is empty
```

That would also solve your second problem because you'd get [`_.isEqual`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) too:

```
_(foo: "bar?q=%s", baz: "qux?q=%s").isEqual(baz: "qux?q=%s", foo: "bar?q=%s")
# true
```

Underscore demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Jad6e/

Comment: I'd say that lodash/underscore is the better solution really, not a wimp out. Well tested code that's already done is always preferable to writing your own wheel.

Comment: @jcollum: A lot of people are prejudiced against adding more dependencies (including me when the dependencies try to take over or are unnecessarily bloated). I tend to have `_` around already.